# Python write values to File txt from Internet

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, apache2

Hi I am have this problem. 
I want write values to txt file useful apache2 and python CGI-SCRIPT. Values is send useful GETMETHOD. BUT BROWSERS speak:

```
=>   30        with open('configuration.txt', 'w') as fp:
<type 'exceptions.IOError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'configuration.txt' 
      args = (13, 'Permission denied') 
      errno = 13 
      filename = 'configuration.txt' 
      message = '' 
      strerror = 'Permission denied'
```

Comment: You can do it running your python script as root, or giving your user ownership to that file(man chown and man chmod on a terminal)

Comment: Thanks Hackerman. it is Solution

Comment: Just for the record, the second choice it's more reliable; and it should be better if you create the file from your python script.

Comment: Thank you for your advice Hackerman .